# How to replace digit between two html tags

Tags: bash, sed

I would like to replace a digit between two HTML tags, but still have a problem and command sed does not work:

- string to replace - `<p key=SaveFile>0</p>`
- new string - `<p key=SaveFile>1</p>`

Code:

```
sed -i 's/\<p key\=SaveFile\>0\<\/p\>/<p key=SaveFile>1<\/p>/' newfile.xml
```

Comment: You don't need to escape `<`, and `=`, you only have to escape `/`.

Comment: obligatory: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/7552

Comment: [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself): `sed -ri 's/(<p key=SaveFile>)[[:digit:]](<\/p>)/\11\2/'`

Comment: @glenn I guess that if it's specifically 0 to 1, then `[[:digit:]]` may as well just be `0`

Answer (score 3):

It's easier if you use another delimiter for `s` like `|` or `@`:

```
echo "<p key=SaveFile>0</p>" | sed 's|<p key=SaveFile>0</p>|<p key=SaveFile>1</p>|'
```

If you want to replace any number between the two tags simply use `[0-9]\+` or `[0-9]+` (with option `-r`):

```
echo "<p key=SaveFile>1234</p>" | sed 's|<p key=SaveFile>[0-9]\+</p>|<p key=SaveFile>1</p>|'
```

Output:

```
<p key=SaveFile>1</p>
```

Application can be

```
sed -i 's|<p key=SaveFile>0</p>|<p key=SaveFile>1</p>|' newfile.xml
```

Or with `g`:

```
sed -i 's|<p key=SaveFile>0</p>|<p key=SaveFile>1</p>|g' newfile.xml
```